# Import Oracle database data to Hive in Talend Big Data

Tags: oracle, hive, bigdata, talend

I have an Oracle 11g database containing a schema which has tables and data.

What I need is to import all this data into Hive. I searched about this, and what I got was use `tSqoopImport`, along with [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsmL2_fxuEQ).

However, when I follow the steps given in the video, I am not understanding what to use for the Hive component to import data.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more the problem? what do you miss for the Hive component? Is it a flow connection question?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop will definitely help you to inject your oracle data in HDFS. If you haven't created the db and tables in hive yet, you can do at the time of doing that while importing data with the help of sqoop. 
Sqoop will create the HiveMetastore at time of loading data. below link will help you too understand.

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_create_hive_table_literal